# Difference between locate and mlocate

Tags: locate

I wanted to install the command `locate`, which is available via `sudo apt-get install`*`mlocate`*.

However, I first ran `sudo apt-get install`*`locate`* which seems to have installed something else.

Typing the command `locate <package>` however seems to call upon *`mlocate`*.

What is the package *`locate`*, and can (should) it be safely removed?

Comment: I believe mlocate was the replacement for the original locate, But That was 15 years ago, and probably, one package is an alias or referer to the other. There is another variant, "slocate" which observed a file's visibility based on user permissions, but I haven't see. That in a long time

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [locate](http://packages.debian.org/) package is the implementation of [locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) from [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/). The [mlocate](http://packages.debian.org/) package is another implementation of the same concept called [mlocate](http://carolina.mff.cuni.cz/~trmac/blog/mlocate). They implement the same basic functionality: quick lookup of file names based on an index that's (typically) rebuilt every night. They differ in some of their functionality beyond basic usage. In particular, GNU locate builds an index of world-readable files only (unless you run it from your account), whereas mlocate builds an index of all files but only lets the calling user see files that it could access. This makes mlocate more useful in most circumstances, but unusable in some unusual installations where it isn't run by the system administrator (because `mlocate` has to be [setuid root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)), and a security risk.

Under Debian and derivatives, if you install both, `locate` will run the `mlocate` implementation, and you need to run `locate.findutils` to run the GNU implementation. This is managed through [alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). If you have both installed, they'll both spend time rebuilding their respective index, but other than that they won't conflict with each other.

Comment: You neglected to mention `mlocate`'s main feature, from which it gets its name ("merging locate"): It provides a version of `updatedb` that reuses its old index to improve update performance by only querying lists of files/subdirectories for directories where the `ctime` has changed.

Comment: "GNU locate builds an index of world-readable files only" are you sure? I found names of a lot of files via locate as regular user, where I had no permissions to in the end

Comment: @rubo77 Your `locate` is probably mlocate and not GNU locate.

Answer (score 11):

mlocate is a newer implemenation of locate. Once you install `mlocate` it

> will change the /usr/bin/locate binary to point to mlocate via the alternatives mechanism.

That is why you get mlocate behaviour if you install in that order.

Details can be found [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mlocate)

Comment: In fact, I never installed `mlocate`, but on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, `/usr/bin/locate -> /etc/alternatives/locate -> /usr/bin/mlocate`